# What is the difference in rewards between a person who is virgin till death and a person who is married?

Tags: heaven, virginity

Nun in the churches are virgins till death. And normal women marries a man.

So what is will be the difference in reward after they die. And reach heaven.

Comment: _These last have wrought but one hour, and thou hast made them **equal unto us**, which have borne the burden and heat of the day. But he answered one of them, and said, Friend, I do thee no wrong: didst not thou agree with me for a penny? Take that thine is, and go thy way: I will give unto this last, even as unto thee._ Matthew 20:13,14. The reward of knowing God . . . .  is to know God. What more do you want ?

Comment: @NigelJ I guess you have misunderstood my question. Many Nun are virgins they don't marry. There have to be a reason. The according to me is reward in heaven. So is there a difference between the nun(who is virgin) and a woman who is  married in terms of reward in heaven

Comment: The reward is the same. Why would there be any difference? What greater reward can there possibly be than knowing God for ever and ever?

Comment: @NigelJ so why Nun choose to be virgins

Comment: Being celibate, or not, is a personal decision and, as Paul the apostle says, 'each has their gift'. Neither is to look down upon the other. Each has their relevant place and function. It is better not to marry. Of course it is. But they are not 'inferior or 'less rewarded' who do so.

Comment: @NigelJ can a Nun marry

Comment: Martin Luther was a monk. And, after the Reformation, he chose to marry.

Comment: According to who? To which denomination?

Comment: If the question is scoped to Catholicism, I can have a response for you!

Comment: @KenGraham well it is not catholicism but, you can answer it as catholicism

Comment: @curiousdannii any, but the mainstream Christianity will be better.

Comment: Which 'stream' is 'mainstream'?

Comment: @NigelJ well the one most of the Christians follow. (I am not a Christian so I don't know about this SORRY)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What is the difference in rewards between a person who is virgin till death and a person who is married?**

***So what is will be the difference in reward after they die. And reach heaven.***

At a Catholic point of view some of the saints in heaven will have special halos.

St. Thomas Aquinas states that virgins, doctors and martyrs will receive special [aureoles](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/aureole):

> An aureole is an exceptional reward corresponding to an exceptional victory: wherefore the three aureoles are assigned in accordance with the exceptional victories in the three conflicts which beset every man. For in the conflict with the flesh, he above all wins the victory who abstains altogether from sexual pleasures which are the chief of this kind; and such is a virgin. Wherefore an aureole is due to virginity. In the conflict with the world, the chief victory is to suffer the world's persecution even until death: wherefore the second aureole is due to martyrs who win the victory in this battle. In the conflict with the devil, the chief victory is to expel the enemy not only from oneself but also from the hearts of others: this is done by teaching and preaching, and consequently the third aureole is due to doctors and preachers.
>
> Some, however, distinguish the three aureoles in accordance with the three powers of the soul, by saying that the three aureoles correspond to the three chief acts of the soul's three highest powers. For the act of the rational power is to publish the truth of faith even to others, and to this act the aureole of doctors is due: the highest act of the irascible power is to overcome even death for Christ's sake, and to this act the aureole of martyrs is due: and the highest act of the concupiscible power is to abstain altogether from the greatest carnal pleasures, and to this act the aureole of virgins is due.
>
> Others again, distinguish the three aureoles in accordance with those things whereby we are most signally conformed to Christ. For He was the mediator between the Father and the world. Hence He was a doctor, by manifesting to the world the truth which He had received from the Father; He was a martyr, by suffering the persecution of the world; and He was a virgin, by His personal purity. Wherefore doctors, martyrs and virgins are most perfectly conformed to Him: and for this reason an aureole is due to them. - [Whether three aureoles are fittingly assigned, those of virgins, of martyrs, and of doctors?](https://www.newadvent.org/summa/5096.htm#article11)

Perhaps in heaven we will be returning closer to Our Divine Author’s intention to be clothed in light as Adam and Eve were in the Garden of Eden.

Just maybe!

[Adam and Eve Clothed in Light Before the Fall - Origin of this belief?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/47688/adam-and-eve-clothed-in-light-before-the-fall-origin-of-this-belief)

Comment: Glad you mentioned the aureoles. ☺